# How to display multiple MKPointAnnotation's callout at once in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpointannotation

In iOS, only one MKPointAnnotation's callout can be displayed at a time. I would like to be able to show all of the pins' callouts on the screen at once. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this method of MKMapView Class:

```
- (void)addAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations;
```

You should add all your MKAnnotation objects to  an array and call the class method with the array.

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *filterLocs=[NSMutableArray array];

for (MKAnnotation *loc in YourMapPointsArray)
{
//add some condition here to manipulate your map points
[filterLocs addObject:loc];
}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:filterLocs];
```

or just make it plain

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:YourMapPointsArray];
```

Comment: Yea, that's easy to implement. I'm trying to show all of the "callouts" of the annotation's at once.                           [eventMap selectAnnotation:point animated:YES]; -- for all of the annotations. The problem is that Apple only allows you to show one at a time.

Comment: I do this in my map and all annotation's appear at a time BTW I did not want any animation so that method was fine to me.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Not following.

Comment: That method is also not in the MKMapView class.

Comment: Are you kidding me??, it is available .I copied it from there for you. See here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/addAnnotations:

Comment: Relax, from Xcode, option clicking did not bringing that up. It did not auto complete either. No need to be rude about it.

Comment: Still, I don't think you are understanding what I am trying to do. I am using addAnotations to add an array of annotations at once. My question pertains to the annotation callouts.

Comment: @user1530580 I am not rude, come on. I like helping people around.

Comment: Okay okay, you want all your callouts at once not annotation points.